# Overloading new returns wrong address

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class station{
    int n;
    float *p;
public:
    station(){};
    station(const station &ob){cout<<"Copy";}
    station operator=(station* a){cout<<"Nai";}
    ~station(){cout<<"Destructor";}
    static float counter;
    friend istream &operator>(istream  &stream, station &d);
    int &getN(){return n;};
    float *&getP(){return p;};
    void* operator new[](size_t size);
    void* operator new(size_t size){station *a;a=::new station;return a;};


};
void* station::operator new[](size_t size){
    station* a;
    a=(::new station[size]);
    int b;
    b=(size)/(sizeof(station));
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++){
        cin>a[i];
    }
   cout<<a;
    return a;
}



float station::counter;
istream &operator>( istream  &stream, station &d){
    cout<<"Dwse arithmo deigmatwn";
    int num;
    stream>>num;
    d.getP()=new float[num];
    d.getN()=num;
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
        stream>>d.getP()[i];
    }
    return stream;
}



int main(){
    station* a;
    a=new station[2];
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

Hello everyone,
This is my first post, so forgive me for any mistakes of mine.

I have created a new class with an overload of new operator and an extractor. My problem is that the address that is returned by new is different from the one that is inside the overloaded operator as you can see in lines where `cout<<a` is stated. However, when i erase the destructor everything goes normal. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you overload the greater-than comparison operator for input stream?

Comment: I am just exercising with overloading operators.

Comment: So, you are exercising how to do the wrong thing?

Comment: The compiler is asking you to allocate uninitialized memory. Some of the memory is used to store the objects, but some is used for internal bookkeeping. You do not know where the objects are going to be placed. Initialize them in the constructor, not the allocator.

Comment: what is an "extractor"? And What are we supposed to see in the line with `cout<<a`? Maybe you should include the output. Btw nicky was refering to your `operator>(istream&...` probably being a typo, do you want `operator>>` ?

Comment: Even if the extractor is >>, the situation remains the same!

Comment: You miss the point. We don't alter meaning of operators without appropriate reasons, especially when we are exercising. Just like no one shall ever use the English word "white" to mean the color black.

Comment: [Mcve] means remove your experiments and noise.  `>` has nothing to do with your problem; don't leave it in.  Repeat until you have distilled down to a short code sample that still reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 3):

When using the `new[]` operator, the compilers can allocate some extra space for the internal bookkeeping (to store e.g. the array size, so when calling `delete[]`, it will know how many object to destroy). That is the difference you see between the "raw" allocation and the final array allocated object address.

That is also the reason, why you should not call `delete` on a memory allocated via `new[]` and vice versa, as it might result in memory leaks (only fist object destroyed), accessing invalid data and/or freeing a bad pointer (technically all UB).

---

**EDIT**

As for the object contents issues, you are not supposed to initialize the objects in the `operator new[]` like this

```
for(int i=0;i<b;i++){
    cin>a[i];
}
```

the operator new/new[] is just to allocate the "raw" memory.

Simply remove that and read the object in the constructor if you wish to (the constructors are called by the compiler automatically for each object in the array), e.g.:

```
station(){cin >> *this}; // or '>' if you really want to keep that
```

But in general, the reading from stream is usually done explicitly, so you can do for example:

```
a=new station[2];
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    cin>a[i];
}
```

in the `main()`.

Comment: However, when i try to access the data using the object's function, it returns garbage!

Comment: I guess that is because the `for(int i=0;i<b;i++){cin>a[i];}` - you are not supposed to initialize the object in the `operator new`, do that in the constructor.